# Is it safe to shift 1-based numbering to 0-based numbering by subtracting 1 if unsigned integers are used?

Tags: c++, c

In a system I am maintaining, users request elements from a collection from a 1-based indexing scheme.  Values are stored in 0-based arrays in C++ / C.

Is the following hypothetical code portable if 0 is erroneously entered as the input to this function?  Is there a better way to validate the user's input when converting 1-based numbering schemes to 0-based?

```
const unsigned int arraySize;
SomeType array[arraySize];    

SomeType GetFromArray( unsigned int oneBasedIndex )
{
  unsigned int zeroBasedIndex = oneBasedIndex - 1;

  //Intent is to check for a valid index.
  if( zeroBasedIndex < arraySize )
  {
    return array[zeroBasedIndex];
  }

  //else... handle the error
}
```

My assumption is that `(unsigned int)( 0 - 1 )` is always greater than `arraySize`; is this true?

The alternative, as some have suggested in their answers below, is to check `oneBasedIndex` and ensure that it is greater than 0:

```
const unsigned int arraySize;
SomeType array[arraySize];    

SomeType GetFromArray( unsigned int oneBasedIndex )
{
  if( oneBasedIndex > 0 && oneBasedIndex <= arraySize )
  {
    return array[oneBasedIndex - 1];
  }

  //else... handle the error
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you don't have `(unsigned int)(0 - 1)`, you have `(unsigned int)0 - (unsigned int)1`.  Both produce the same value because 0 minus 1 both involve regular `int` and the subtraction produces -1; but for other values, ordinary `int` might overflow, while `unsigned int` never does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unsigned types, `0-1` is the maximum value for that type, so it's always `>= arraySize`. In other words, yes that is absolutely safe.

Comment: On most implementations, yes. On all implementations? No. Unsigned underflow is allowed to throw some form of hardware exception in the standard.

Comment: Not really. If size_t is larger than unsigned int, it's possible for the "wrapped" value to end up somewhere in the middle of an array (e.g., a 64-bit system that still uses 32-bit `int`s).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Where in the standard does it say that?

Comment: Maximal value of that type, in this case `unsigned int`; so `0U - 1U` gives you `UINT_MAX`, and since `arraySize` has type `unsigned int` as well, `arraySize` is certainly no more than `UINT_MAX`.  If you start mixing in `unsigned long` or `size_t` type values, it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: @torek: No, it doesn't always give you `UINT_MAX`. That's the point. It does on most platforms, but certainly not all.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Fair enough; deleted my answer.

Comment: @BillyONeal: I realize this is not the actual standard, but in n1124, see section 6.2.5 (Types), p. 34, paragraph 9: "Acomputation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."

Comment: @torek: But this isn't an overflow case, this is an underflow case. Reducing the result modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented does not help you; the reduction would still leave a negative number, which still wouldn't be valid in an `unsigned`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz For C, it's 6.2.5(9), "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.", for C++ I have to search, may take a bit.

Comment: For the purposes of the C standard, underflow and overflow "mean the same thing" for unsigned types.  They're defined as GF(2**k) arithmetic.

Comment: @DanielFischer: How does "is reduced modulo the number that is one greater" a help when the number is already negative? Any reduction would still be a negative number.

Comment: @torek + DanielFischer + JerryCoffin: Nevermind; [ouah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897698/is-it-safe-to-shift-1-based-numbering-to-0-based-numbering-by-subtracting-1-if-u/9897825#9897825) found it already. :)

Comment: Alas, I have to fall back on "well, back when Dennis and I talked about it" kind of stuff. :-)  The separation of different kinds of "over/under-flow" is meant only to apply to floating-point.  FPUs do, of course, distinguish these.  However, underflow in FPU means "vanishing towards zero" rather than "went to negative infinity", which is still considered an "overflow"!

Answer (score 5):

Unsigned integers never overflow in C++ and in C.

For C++ language:

> (C++11, 3.9.1p4) "Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer. 46)"

and footnote 46):

> "46) This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type."

and for C language:

> (C11, 6.2.5p9) "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
>   because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
>   represented by the resulting type."

Comment: This is an **underflow** though; keep that in mind. I'm not positive this statement makes the above code safe.

Comment: @BillyONeal the point of this answer is to show that unsigned "overflow" / "underflow" are not undefined behavior but well defined.

Comment: But this answer does not say that. The standard says "... **reduced** modulo the number one greater....", which doesn't help you; reducing by anything is still a negative number which still is not valid in an unsigned type.

Comment: @BillyONeal of course it is. Take for example, `unsigned int a = -1;` this is well defined and ruled by the integral conversions, see C++11, 4.7

Comment: Ah, I see now. +1. (Though I would note that in your answer)

Answer (score 4):

Chances are good that it's safe, but for many purposes, there's a much simpler way: allocate one extra spot in your array, and just ignore element 0.

Comment: Certainly better than the OP's proposed solution; +1.

Comment: Either way, validating the index would still be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

No, for example 0-1 is 0xffffffff in 4-byte unsigned int, what if your array is really that big? 
32 bit is ok because 0xffffffff exceeds limit, the code breaks when compile in 64 bit if the array is that big.

Just check for oneBasedIndex > 0

Comment: The question is whether or not the check the OP already has (the zeroBasedIndex < arraySize bit) is sufficient. If the result was `0xFFFFFFFFu`, this check would certainly be sufficient, because the array size will certainly never be that high.

Comment: "Just check" should be 'Just "add" check', yes the array size can be that high for 64 bit compiles. Tested and compiled, if the author knows it can't be that high, that should be suffice. Generally, you want your code to survive future maintenance as much as it can.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `oneBasedIndex` is greater than zero...

Comment: -1: It's unsigned. It can't be less than zero. That's the whole point.

Comment: Fair enough, I did misread that. But this answer still does not answer the OP's question, so I'm not removing my downvote.

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions about the behavior of unsigned ints, but it does give a simple solution to the overall problem.  Perhaps I will rephrase my question.